# When resolving merge conflicts with git, do resolveable differences merged automatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, merge, git-merge

Using git, I have some merge conflicts.

I have tried using egit plugin for eclipse to color the diffs.

After I resolve I see the obvious and can-be-resolved-without-me diffs were not resolved by egit.

How do you see colored diffs and auto-resolve the resolvable diffs?

Comment: please elaborate the problem, attach code, error messages.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you got conflicts in egit during a merge, rebase or a pull and you started the diff-solving by double-clicking the files?

If that is correct, please note that it is necessary to right-click on the files with problems and select merge-tool.

After merging a file a `git add` is necessary and after fixing all conflicts you have to commit.